# How to fix the "request time out" error in Xcode archives

Tags: ios, xcode

Sometime we can get an error, when Xcode try to fetch the accounts from apple server. the error is shown below

[image: Request time out image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are solutions out there to solve this, but their is one more simple solution for this type of error
go to Xcode

- Xcode Preference
- Source Control Tab

[xcode preference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkctJ.png)

Here you can see the "**refresh server status automatically**" title.
**tick the checkbox** and close the preference. then again try to build.
if it didn’t work, try to build again after some mins. it always works for me.

Hope this helps.